# How to calculate Diffential Entropy (DE) in Python?

Tags: python, eeg, array-signal-processing

I am working with a data which is actually the popular EEG data called DEAP. It basically is a 3D array of size (40, 40, 8064) and here is the link to the official dataset website: https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/mmv/datasets/deap/

I am planning to extract the differential entropy (DE) of it but I am having difficulty implementing it in Python. Do you know a straightforward code to do it? Also, is there any library/module in Python for doing it? (Like the Welch module in the Scipy library for calculating PSD)

Comment: According to [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy), differential entropy is defined by the negated expectation of the log probability density function (PDF), not the power spectral density. You either need to estimate the PDF or the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) (i.e. an inverse cumulative distribution function) before plugging into one of the equations to calculate DE.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.differential_entropy.html